# Why can't I use class operator Implicit to convert to a static array of char

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Using Delphi 11.

I can use `class operator implicit` to convert to a dynamic array of characters.
I can also use it to convert to a static array of integers or strings, or just about any other type.
But I can't use it to convert to a static array of characters.
What am I missing?

```
type
  tStaticArrayOfInteger = array [ 1 .. 2 ] of integer;
  tStaticArrayOfString  = array [ 1 .. 2 ] of string;
  tStaticArrayOfChar    = array [ 1 .. 2 ] of char;   // <-  Trouble maker
  tDynamicArrayOfChar   = array of char;

type
  tThing = record
    private
      fIgnoreThisValue : boolean;
    public
      class operator Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tStaticArrayOfInteger;
      class operator Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tStaticArrayOfString;
      class operator Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tStaticArrayOfChar;
      class operator Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tDynamicArrayOfChar;
  end;

class operator tThing.Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tStaticArrayOfInteger;
begin
  Result [1] :=  8;
  Result [2] := 21;
end;

class operator tThing.Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tStaticArrayOfString;
begin
  Result [1] := 'hello';
  Result [2] := 'world';
end;

class operator tThing.Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tStaticArrayOfChar;
begin
  Result [1] := 'H';
  Result [2] := 'W';
end;

class operator tThing.Implicit ( const X : tThing ) : tDynamicArrayOfChar;
begin
  setlength ( Result, 2 );
  Result [0] := 'h';
  Result [1] := 'w';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aThing                : tThing;
  aStaticArrayOfInteger : tStaticArrayOfInteger;
  aStaticArrayOfString  : tStaticArrayOfString;
  aStaticArrayOfChar    : tStaticArrayOfChar;
  aDynamicArrayOfChar   : tDynamicArrayOfChar;
begin
  aThing . fIgnoreThisValue := false;
  aStaticArrayOfInteger := aThing; // This works fine
  aStaticArrayOfString  := aThing; // This works fine

  aStaticArrayOfChar    := aThing; // <-- Incompatible types:
                                   // 'tStaticArrayOfChar' and 'tThing'

  aDynamicArrayOfChar   := aThing; // This works fine
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the actual cause but `'H'` is not a single character but one character long string. I believe you would have to typecast `'H'` to char variable first for this to work as you intended.

Comment: @SilverWarior This is an odd statement. Let me ask you how you would write a character literal in Delphi. Or do you somehow believe that character literals don't exist? I'd give you a link to the documentation for character literals if only Embarcadero could keep their servers alive more than a couple of hours at a time.

Comment: @david This looks like a defect to me. You should submit a bug report, but first you'll need to wait for Embarcadero to get their servers up again.

Comment: The content of the routines is irrelevant.  I could've just left them empty to illustrate the problem.  I thought that filling in some code would make it feel more concrete.  The problem is that Delphi refuses to let me execute the routine at all regardless of what code is in the routine.

Comment: The problem is very clear. It would be even clearer if you removed all the other operators and just left the one that fails. But you know what to do about it now at least.

Comment: Reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-44280